# Remove the first set of characters from the string in Python

Tags: python

I have to compare only the unique value here. To do this I have to remove all the previous characters and compare it.For example my string is

```
a1=/1/1/auniquevalue
a2=/1/10/buniquevalue
```

To compare the unique value what I have tried is

```
a1=a1[4:]  
a1=uniquevalue
```

It worked well.

But if I get two digit number which is same like in a2 then the a2 value will be a2=/uniquevalue and the comparison is failing.

How do I get the unique value invariable of number of digits. And the uniquevalue is very length one and it differs every time
So basically I have to remove all the characters till the third slashes

Comment: `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',a2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `re.sub` here, and remove all content up to and including the final (third) forward slash:

```
a1 = "/1/1/auniquevalue"
a1_out = re.sub(r'^.*/', '', a1)
print(a1_out)
```

This prints:

```
auniquevalue
```

Another option, assuming there would always be three slashes, would be to use `split()`:

```
a1 = "/1/1/auniquevalue"
a1_out = a1.split('/')[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to remove all the characters till the third slashes

You might use `.split` method of `str` for that task following way:

```
a1='/1/1/auniquevalue'
a2='/1/10/buniquevalue'
a1uniq = a1.split('/',3)[-1]
a2uniq = a2.split('/',3)[-1]
print(a1uniq)  # auniquevalue
print(a2uniq)  # buniquevalue
```

`split` accept 2nd optional argument: maximum number of splits to do, `[-1]` means get last element. Setting this optional argument guarantees that it will work correctly also if there is `/` inside your uniquevalue, that is

```
a3 = '/1/10/blah/blah/blah'
a3uniq = a3.split('/',3)[-1]
print(a3uniq)  # blah/blah/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a1="/1/10/buniquevalue"
a1[a1.rfind("/")+1:]
```

Bye